# Cannot open index.php sites while setting https with nginx

Tags: php, nginx

I am using nginx + php-fpm on my centos server and while I was trying to set up https, with nginx.conf revised, I find that only the 'index.php' cannot be properly accessed.

working:

https://ip/index.php

https://domain/*.php (* != index)

https://domain/*/*.php

http://ip/index.php

http://domain/index.php

not working:

https://domain/index.php

my nginx.conf looks like this:

```
server {
listen 443 default_server;
server_name localhost;
ssl on;
root /home/wwwroot/default;
index index.html index.htm;
ssl_certificate   cert/*****.pem;
ssl_certificate_key  cert/*****.key;
ssl_session_timeout 5m;
ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE:ECDH:AES:HIGH:!NULL:!aNULL:!MD5:!ADH:!RC4;
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
location / {
    root /home/wwwroot/default;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
}
location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    root           /home/wwwroot/default;
    fastcgi_pass  unix:/tmp/php-cgi.sock;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  HTTPS   on;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
    include fastcgi.conf;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please define _"not working"_. What is happening?

Comment: I believe your `root` and `index` configs should be at the `server` level and not inside `location / { ... }`. I would remove them and add `index.php` to your first `index` config

Comment: Sorry for not explaining clearly, but now everything seems fine...'Not working' means that the navigation would take me to the default index pages... like the one in /usr/local/nginx/html/index.html..., while those working pages was working properly... I'm not sure what was happening, but now https://domain/index.php works...

Comment: this piece of code is copied from the original nginx.conf for port 80 except the changes about ssl&https... and from the original code the root and index settings exist both the server level and the location / {} level...

Comment: Fair enough. I was just comparing to my php-fpm host configs. It does seem odd to define `root` and `index` twice though